# Is there a way to create 10 millions row of random dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, numpy, dataset

I would like to create random dataset consists of 10 million rows. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to create date column with specific range (example from 01.01.2021-31.12.2021).

I tried with oracle sql, but could not find a way to do that. There is way that I can do in excel, but excel can not handle 10 millions row of data. Therefore, I though Python can be the best way to do that, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: You can do it in SQL or PL/SQL by adding numbers to dates.  This will always be faster than an upload over a network from Python.  (Not that 10 M rows is particularly big)  See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create random dataset consists of 10 million rows. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to create date column with specific range (example from 01.01.2021-31.12.2021).
>
> I tried with oracle sql, but could not find a way to do that.

You can use the `DBMS_RANDOM` package with a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01'
       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, DATE '2022-01-01' - DATE '2021-01-01')
         AS random_date
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000000;
```

Which outputs:

| RANDOM_DATE |
| --- |
| 2021-11-25 00:53:13 |
| 2021-08-28 22:33:35 |
| 2021-02-11 23:28:50 |
| 2021-12-10 05:39:00 |
| 2021-01-10 22:02:47 |
| ... |
| 2021-01-01 16:39:13 |
| 2021-10-30 20:58:21 |
| 2021-03-14 06:27:34 |
| 2021-10-11 00:24:03 |
| 2021-04-20 03:53:54 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xnDdL3NY)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) combined with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': np.random.choice(
            pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='D'), size=10_000_000
        )
    }
)
```

Example:

```
              date
0       2021-04-05
1       2021-02-01
2       2021-09-22
3       2021-10-17
4       2021-04-28
...            ...
9999995 2021-07-24
9999996 2021-03-15
9999997 2021-07-28
9999998 2021-11-01
9999999 2021-03-20

[10000000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most python IDE's will come with a random module which you need because no random function is built in with python.

To get 10000000 rows of data a loop like the one below will probably work.

```python
#Imports the random module
import random

#Creates a loop that will run 10 million times
for i in range(0,10000000):
  
  #Prints a random number between one and ten on each new row
  print(random.randint(0,10)
```

It will take a while but will work if this is what you are after?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).